# Presenting an Alert in SwiftUI using MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui, alert

I'm trying to build an app using SwiftUI and an MVVM architecture. I'd like to have my View present an alert whenever its ViewModel deems it necessary—say, when it has a new result of some sort available from the Model. So suppose whenever the VM detects a new result it sets its `status` accordingly:

**The ViewModel:**

```
enum Status {
    case idle
    case computing
    case newResultAvailable
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var status = Status.idle

    ...
}
```

**The View:**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var vm = MyViewModel()

    @State private var announcingResult = false {
        didSet {
            // reset VM status when alert is dismissed
            if announcingResult == false {
                vm.status = .idle
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
        .alert(isPresented: $announcingResult) {
            Alert(title: Text("There's a new result!"),
                message: nil,
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
}
```

Apple has designed the `.alert()` modifier to take a binding as its first argument, so that the alert is displayed whenever the bound property becomes `true`. Then, when the alert is dismissed, the bound property is automatically set to `false`.

**My question is:** 
How can I have the alert appear whenever the VM's `status` becomes `.newResultAvailable`? It seems to me that that's how proper MVVM should function, and it feels very much in the spirit of all the SwiftUI WWDC demos, but I can't find a way…

Comment: Is there any document reference or explanation as to **why** this doesn't work? I can't seem to understand the reason behind that.

Comment: @Rikh it does work whenever you set `announcingResult` to `true`. But my goal was to have the alert present whenever `vm.status` became a certain value… and the code above has no provision to make that happen. That's why @asperi's answer below is necessary.

Comment: Ahh i misread your example above. Apologies. I have found that having a `@Published` value to control the alert directly inside the view model also doesn't cause it to appear inside the `View`. So was looking for answers to that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is possible approach (tested & works with Xcode 11.3+)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var vm = MyViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        let announcingResult = Binding<Bool>(
            get: { self.vm.status == .newResultAvailable },
            set: { _ in self.vm.status = .idle }
        )
        return Text("Hello")
            .alert(isPresented: announcingResult) {
                Alert(title: Text("There's a new result!"),
                    message: nil,
                    dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
    }
}
```

also sometimes the following notation can be preferable

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello")
        .alert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>(
            get: { self.vm.status == .newResultAvailable },
            set: { _ in self.vm.status = .idle }
        )) {
            Alert(title: Text("There's a new result!"),
                message: nil,
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Asperi! That looks terrific. I'll give it a try.
It hadn't occurred to me that I might have to do manual bindings… I never have thus far, but that does seem to be an elegant solution.
If there's one to be had that avoids them I'll be delighted; if not, I think this will work!

Comment: My overriding of Bindings no longer work in Xcode 11.5 as @user12208004 points out. This kind of behaviour seems to be broken.

Comment: I don't have Xcode 11.5. Retested with Xcode 12 - works fine. Make sure you modify view model published properties on main queue.

Comment: I updated to Xcode 11.6, and it works fine too. Thanks @Asperi

Answer (score 6):

I have created a helper class

```
class AlertProvider {
    struct Alert {
        var title: String
        let message: String
        let primaryButtomText: String
        let primaryButtonAction: () -> Void
        let secondaryButtonText: String
    }

    @Published var shouldShowAlert = false

    var alert: Alert? = nil { didSet { shouldShowAlert = alert != nil } }
}
```

In the VM it can be used like this

```
var alertProvider = AlertProvider()

func showAlert() {
    alertProvider.alert = AlertProvider.Alert(
        title: "The Locatoin Services are disabled",
        message: "Do you want to turn location on?",
        primaryButtomText: "Go To Settings",
        primaryButtonAction: { [weak self] in
            self?.appSettingsHandler.openAppSettings()
        },
        secondaryButtonText: "Cancel"
    )
}
```

We can also use an extension for the Alert View class

```
extension Alert {
    init(_ alert: AlertProvider.Alert) {
        self.init(title: Text(alert.title),
                  message: Text(alert.message),
                  primaryButton: .default(Text(alert.primaryButtomText),
                                          action: alert.primaryButtonAction),
                  secondaryButton: .cancel(Text(alert.secondaryButtonText)))
    }
}
```

Then the View would use it in the following way

```
.alert(isPresented: $viewModel.alertProvider.shouldShowAlert ) {
        guard let alert = viewModel.alertProvider.alert else { fatalError("Alert not available") }

        return Alert(alert)
}
```

I believe further improvements can be made in this approach

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Wouldn't you need to send the change coming from the AlertProvider class (shouldShowAlert) through to your view from inside the VM before this will work, or am I missing something?

Comment: @dabarnard is right. The alert is not appearing